# Reorder timestamps pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a `pandas` `column` that contain `timestamps` that are unordered. When I sort them it works fine except for the values `H:MM:SS`.

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['8:00:00','9:00:00','10:00:00','20:00:00','24:00:00','26:20:00'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.sort_values(by='A',ascending=True)

Out:
          A
2  10:00:00
3  20:00:00
4  24:00:00
5  26:20:00
0   8:00:00
1   9:00:00
```

Ideally, I'd like to add a zero before 5 letter `strings`. If I convert them all to `time delta` it converts the times after midnight into 1 day plus n amount of hours. e.g.

```
df['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['A'])

                A
0 0 days 08:00:00
1 0 days 09:00:00
2 0 days 10:00:00
3 0 days 20:00:00
4 1 days 00:00:00
5 1 days 02:20:00
```

Intended Output:

```
          A
0  08:00:00
1  09:00:00
2  10:00:00
3  20:00:00
4  24:00:00
5  26:20:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to sort by the column as *timedelta*, you can convert the column to *timedelta* and use `argsort` on it to create the sorting order to sort the data frame:

```
df.iloc[pd.to_timedelta(df.A).argsort()]

#          A
#0   8:00:00
#1   9:00:00
#2  10:00:00
#3  20:00:00
#4  24:00:00
#5  26:20:00
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Thanks @Psidom